# That guy who says nothing except to criticize those who do

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What’s a word for a person who sits silently in a discussion except to harp on what another person says?

For example, at a business meeting, one person doesn't add any helpful ideas, but is quick to tear down those of everyone else.

I thought “jaybird” might be it, but that just means chatterbox.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to ELU. Can you give us a bit of context?  Because, that would sway which word would be most appropriate.

Comment: I would use it as a pejorative descriptor or label. “Kibbutzer” might be close if it was a word, but my spell checker kicked it. “Troll” is in the neighborhood.

Comment: Kibbitzer. Kibbutzer would be someone living on a Kibbutz. Kibbitzing is more general talking amongst yourselves about a subject. But, I meant flesh out your question. Tell us what in context you need the word. "I'm writing a story about a man whose father ...." That sort of thing.

Comment: I used the wrong word, I meant “kibitz”, which means to look on and offer unwelcome advice, especially at a card game. This is close. I’m sorry I can’t communicate the context better than I already have: it is to be used as a pejorative descriptor or label.

Comment: I'm going to try to revise your question so you can see what I mean by contextualizing your question.

Comment: Please read my edit and revise it to fit your needs a bit better.

Comment: *That guy who says nothing except to criticize those who do say nothing except to criticize those who do say n...* That's just "That guy who says nothing except to criticize"! Wait a minute , a "guy who says nothing except to criticize those who do say nothing"--does he criticize himself? a) If he does not, then it's a hypocrit. b) If he does criticize himself, perhaps only himself, then its an apparent paradox, but not because of self-referentiallity, but because the criticism is not critical unless it can establish something that should have been said. If that's missing, see a).

Comment: David, I think your revision works well enough. The uses that come to mind most recently had to do with online discussions, but a work environment is also apt.

Comment: I think “kibitz/kibitzer” is a good word. I feel it has the negative connotation that I want to convey.

Answer (score 0):

A [naysayer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer) is someone who is "denies, refuses, opposes, or is skeptical or cynical about something".

A [cynic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynic) is someone who is "a faultfinding captious critic".

A [disparager](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparager) is someone who disparages, which is to "speak slightingly about".

Each of them have their own nuances and appropriateness for the work place.